# Cumulative Distribution Function with New Random Variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm really new to statistics and probability so sorry if this is a really basic question. I just wasn't sure how to do it. I tried looking it up but can't find much information.

If I'm given a cdf for a random variable X, how do I find it for a new random variable Y which was in terms of X? Do I just plug in Y? My example is following:

```
FX(x) = 1 −1/x
for 1 < x < ∞
Find the cdf for the new random variable Y = -X + 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
F_Y(y) & = \Pr(Y\le y) = \Pr(-X+2\le y) = \Pr(X\ge 2-y) \\[8pt]
& = 1-\Pr(X\le 2-y) = F_X(2-y)
\end{align}
provided $2-y\ge 1$, which is the same as $y\le 1$.

If $y>1$ then
$$
F_Y(y) = \Pr(Y\le y) = \Pr(-X+2\le y) = \Pr(X\ge 2-y) = 1.
$$

Your way of phrasing the question makes me a bit suspicious: I wonder if you are expecting some prescribed way of solving a problem, rather than expecting to figure it out based on information you have.  The latter is the way to do math.